# Calling the same FDQuery a second time can fail because the first call sets the size of its string parameters

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, firedac

This simple call works fine the first time (The database is SQL Server 2014, and **email** is a varchar(128) column with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation).

```
qryLogMail.ParamByName('email').Value := email;
qryLogMail.ExecSQL;
```

But the second time fails when the parameter value is larger than the previous one.

```
[FireDAC][Stan]-704. Variable length data parameter [EMAIL] overflow. Value length - [22], parameter data maximum length - [21]
```

The first call has set the parameter size, so the second call can't exceed it.

Manually setting the parameter size solves it sometimes, but not always.

```
qryLogMail.ParamByName('email').Size := Length(email);
qryLogMail.ParamByName('email').Value := email;
qryLogMail.ExecSQL;
```

The only trustworthy solution I have found is to recreate the parameters before each call.

```
qryLogMail.Params.Clear;
qryLogMail.Params.CreateParam(ftWideString, 'email', ptInput);
qryLogMail.ParamByName('email').Value := email;
qryLogMail.ExecSQL;
```

But this is very annoying when you have many parameters (you have also removed the non-string parameters and you must recreate them all). Do you know a way to prevent the FDParameters to set their size at the call, or to recreate all the params (something like the FetchParams of the ClientDataset) ?

Comment: This has been removed in Tokyo. In version of FireDAC older than Berlin I cannot see anything more than a simple comparison of parameter `Size` with the value `Length` which when exceeds, this exception is raised (inside `TFDParam.InternalSetValue`). What is the DBMS that you use? How is your `email` column declared in database (if it's variable length, its size and encoding are important)? And just to be clear, you don't set the `Size` by yourself. It's determined (badly?) after the first `ExecSQL` call, or what happens?

Comment: Thanks Victoria. It's SQL Server 2014, with a varchar(128) column and SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation. No I don't define the size myself, I leave it with its zero default value (although changing it to 128 on the IDE when defining the query, doesn't help).

Comment: Is it possible to prepare the query in firedac? If so, does that help?

Comment: I will try Berlin, but I would prefer to solve it without needing to switching to a new version of Delphi (which can cause new problems).

Comment: Yes, it's possible, I will try to call to Prepare explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, looked into the docs. Should be automatically called before ExecSQL anyways.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with my older version (FireDAC 8.0.1). I've setup the same column on LocalDB instance of SQL Server 2014 and ran your code with no problems. What's more, parameters are not described by FireDAC for commands executed on SQL Server (see e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46428723/8041231)). So I have no idea what can setup `Size` in your case. I don't have your version, but setting `Value` so as preparing command should not modify `Size` of the parameter. So string that you assign to the parameter is shorter than 128 chars and longer than value from last execution?

Comment: If so, does it mean that `Size` is setup by `ExecSQL` call (can you inspect that)? And just to be sure, are we talking about `INSERT` or `UPDATE` kind of command, not some complex one or stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks for trying. Yes, the second string is shorter than 128 chars and larger than the first one. It's a simple INSERT instruction (although it happens with all commands). And finally, yes, the ExecSQL has changed the Size property of the parameter to the length of the first string.

Comment: Damn, I was trying to code a Minimal Demo, and I found that it works fine on an small VCL application. It must be something about running on a server (both a background service and a REST server), I will kepp tryng to build that minimal, verifiable, sample.

Comment: Thank you Marc for your attitude. So it seems not to be FireDAC issue in the end, as you say. I'd be hlad to help with any FireDAC issue but an MVCE is a must in this case. At least I can repeat myself for future readers, the mentioned exception was removed in Tokyo. The `Size` property should not be changed, IMHO when you don't explicitly prepare the command (and not all drivers can describe parameters, at least in Tokyo for which I can speak). Unfortunately, I cannot see the source of Berlin, so I'm a bit out of help here.