# Delphi IBX to Firedac Migration For Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

I migrated an IBX application which have 500+ forms to Firedac. I mapped the datatypes with Delphi Help. Here is my data mapping:

```
  with ADB.FormatOptions do
  begin
    OwnMapRules := True;
    DefaultParamDataType := ftVariant;

    MapRules.Clear;
    with MapRules.Add do
    begin
      PrecMax        := 4;
      PrecMin        := 0;
      ScaleMax       := 0;
      ScaleMin       := 0;
      SourceDataType := dtFmtBCD;
      TargetDataType := dtInt16;
    end;

    with MapRules.Add do
    begin
      PrecMax        := 10;
      PrecMin        := 5;
      ScaleMax       := 0;
      ScaleMin       := 0;
      SourceDataType := dtFmtBCD;
      TargetDataType := dtInt32;
    end;

    with MapRules.Add do
    begin
      PrecMax        := 18;
      PrecMin        := 11;
      ScaleMax       := 0;
      ScaleMin       := 0;
      SourceDataType := dtFmtBCD;
      TargetDataType := dtInt64;
    end;

    with MapRules.Add do
    begin
      SourceDataType := dtFmtBCD;
      TargetDataType := dtDouble;
    end;

    with MapRules.Add do
    begin
      SourceDataType := dtDateTimeStamp;
      TargetDataType := dtDateTime;
    end;
  end;
```

Is this mapping is true? If it's false, how do I it's true?

When a FDQuery has parameters and a parameter has no value on execute the query,an exception occured :

> [FireDAC][Phys][FB]-338. Param [XXX] type changed from [ftVariant] to [ftInteger]. Query must be reprepared. Possible reason: an assignment to a TFDParam.AsXXX property implicitly changed the parameter data type. Hint: use the TFDParam.Value or appropriate TFDParam.AsXXX property

How do I solve this problem? Thanks for everything.

Comment: Are you asking whether a BCD-format field can be mapped to an integer?

Comment: I ask true Firedac Firebird mapping for posibble situations  @MartynA

Comment: Well, surely whether your BCD data can be *safely* mapped to integers depends on the values actually stored.  So I think it's an unaswerable question, from that point of view.

Comment: "When .... parameter has no value" - that means it should be SQL `NULL` as far as I can understand. Also, Delphi `variant` type has `null` as possible value. I did not work with AnyDAC, but maybe relevant (`TParam` type is maybe shared by all db-aware-compatible access libraries) experience with Delphi XE2 dbExpress shows that one has to make two steps and in proper order: `Par1 := Query1.ParamByName('...'); Par1.Clear {sets *both* Null value and null/variant type};  Par1.DataType := ftInteger {or any other expected type};`

Comment: Think about `DefaultParamDataType := ftVariant;` - maybe you can remove that line, or put something like `ftNull` or anything. Maybe there can be some special rules for `NULL` value to be casted to any of `TargetDataType` without re-conversions. Sadly original AnyDAc site is down, including the documentation there, but google for "anydac firebird parameter null Query must be reprepared" and there are at least some links

Comment: example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428723

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using the mapping below:

```
with ADB.FormatOptions do
begin
  OwnMapRules := True;

  with MapRules.Add do
  begin
    SourceDataType := dtDateTimeStamp;
    TargetDataType := dtDateTime;
  end;

  with MapRules.Add do
  begin
    SourceDataType := dtDateTime;
    TargetDataType := dtDateTimeStamp;
  end;
end;
```

After than I build my application and test it. The Result is OK for me.

Comment: So `Think about DefaultParamDataType := ftVariant; - maybe you can remove that line` worked

Comment: I don't use ftvariant as you see. The problem is integer and float mapping.

Comment: yep, you used it, but you removed it by mu suggestion. I quoted myself from the earlier comments at question.