# How can a TClientDataSet determine what type of database it is (remotely) connected to?

Tags: delphi, client-server, firedac, tclientdataset, remobjects

Under FireDAC, I have a `TFDConnection -> TFDQuery -> TDataSetProvider` in a server app and a `TClientDataSet` in a client app. They are connected through the [RemObjects Remoting SDK](http://www.remotingsdk.com/ro/). (The `TClientDataSet.RemoteServer` is set to a `TRODataSnapConnection`).

The `TFDConnection` may be connected to different database types.

With the `TClientDataSet` code in the client, (how) can I determine the database type?

For a simple app containing all these components I could scan the datamodule for a component of type `TDataSetProvider` with name `TClientDataSet.ProviderName` at design time (messy but doable), but for this client/server architecture I have no idea how to do this...

The `TRODataSnapConnection` only has a ServerName property set to `TTServer.RDMDataBasis`. TTServer is the server application, `RDMDataBasis` is a `TRemoteDataModule` in there.

Comment: XY Problem? Why would you need this? You're supposed to connect to middle tier without concern for how / what persistence layer it connects to.

Comment: @CraigYoung You are correct. [This is the X from the Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673049/parameter-asstring-failing-under-oracle-mssql-parameter-value-2-byte-chars-und)

Comment: Any solution how to pass database type from client to server?