# Setting Oracle CLOB field to null fails with ORA 22275

Tags: oracle, delphi, clob, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

We have one(!) customer where setting an Oracle CLOB field to NULL fails with

```
[FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA 22275 - Invalid LOB locator specified
```

The query that is sent to the database<sup>*</sup> is

```
update tt_hrs set
 TT_INFO = ?
where
 TT_HRS_ID = ?

Params:
0 -  : <NULL>
1 -  : 276727
```

Querying the dataset through FireDAC shows me that `lDataset.Fields[i].DataType` for field `TT_HRS` is `ftWideMemo`.

Many things I find on the internet are associated with the 'old way' (Oracle 8.0.5 IIRC) of updating CLOBS where you used

```
UPDATE ClobTable
SET
  Value = EMPTY_CLOB()
WHERE
  Id = :Id
RETURNING
  Value
INTO
  :Value
```

but AFAIK these kind of statements are no longer required.

In SQLPLUS I can execute these without issues on our own Oracle 12c database, so [the difference between `EMPTY_CLOB()` and `NULL`](http://nuijten.blogspot.com/2009/11/empty-clob-is-not-null-its-not-null.html) does not seem to matter:

```
update tt_hrs set tt_info='test' where tt_hrs_id=276727;
update tt_hrs set tt_info=NULL where tt_hrs_id=276727;
update tt_hrs set tt_info=empty_clob() where tt_hrs_id=276727;
```

- As the error message shows we use FireDAC in a Delphi Tokyo 10.2.2
  32-bit Windows app.
- There is no NOT NULL constraint on the field, it is not in an index,
  there are no triggers.
- The client uses OracleDB12 Release 1.
- Our update code is generated by FireDAC from a TClientDataSet
  connected to a grid that the user edits.

**Question**:

Is there anything in Oracle settings that might explain this behavior?
Maybe they set some 'compatibility mode' to support old applications or something... I'm not familiar enough with Oracle.

Note: It wouldn't by any chance be related to the issue with 2-byte chars [I reported earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673049/parameter-asstring-failing-under-oracle-mssql-parameter-value-2-byte-chars-und/47904988#47904988)?

Clutching at straws here...

<sup>* We can log this because we have a TDataSetProvider descendant that logs what is being sent in an overridden `DoBeforeExecute`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We have never been able to find the exact cause of this, but have found a workaround.

The affected code all works through `TClientDataSet`, and we already used a `TDataSetProvider` descendant with an overriden `DoBeforeExecute` to log the actual SQL sent to the database (for debugging purposes). This calls a logging procedure in our code and we have added the below to that:

```
// Force parameter to ftOraClob when NULL:
if TFDQuery(TDataSetProvider(Sender).Dataset).Connection.Params.DriverID = S_FD_OraId then
  for i := 0 to params.count-1 do
    if (params[i].DataType = ftMemo) and (VarIsNull(params[i].Value) or VarIsClear(params[i].Value)) then
       params[i].DataType := ftOraClob;
```

This forces the `AddField` subroutine in `TSQLResolver.GenUpdateSQL` in `Datasnap.Provider.pas`to follow the path:

```
else if UseFieldInUpdate(Field) then
begin
  Result := True;
  if (Field.DataType = ftOraClob) and (not InformixLob) then
  begin
    NoParam := True;
    if InObject then
      SQL.Add(string.Format(' %s.%s = EMPTY_CLOB(),', [Alias, QuoteFullName(Field.FullName, PSQLInfo(Tree.Data).QuoteChar),   { Do not localize }
        Field.FullName]))
```

thereby writing `= EMPTY_CLOB()` instead of `= NULL`, which the Oracle DB happily accepts.

Note: We test for ftMemo because we have a mapping rule active that says

```
with AConnection.FormatOptions.MapRules.Add do 
begin
  SourceDataType := dtWideHMemo;
  TargetDataType := dtMemo;
end;
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47904988/512728)
If you don't have this, testing for `ftWideMemo` would be required.